# Compare duration an return a percentage of matching

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, compare, percentage

I need to compare two duration and generate a percentage of matching.

For example, I have a trusted duration, and a second duration that need to be compared with the first one.

There is a tolerance of 8%, which means the second duration can be 8% more or less longer than the trusted one.

if duration2 > duration1 - 8% && if duration2 < duration1 + 8%
    return 100%

And finally my function have to return the percentage of matching between the two duration.

Do you know how to do that ?

Thank you !

Comment: Which part don’t you know how to translate into JavaScript?

Comment: How to get a good percentage of matching !

Answer (score 0):

Because:

- 100% of value --> 1 * value
- 100% - 8% of value --> 92% of value --> 0.92 * value
- 100% + 8% of value --> 108% of value --> 1.08 * value

it is possible to do the following

```
if (duration2 > duration1 * 0.92 && duration2 < duration1 * 1.08) {
    return 1; // if inside -8% +8% returns 100%
} else {
   // If not in the -8% or +8% returns percentage
   return Math.abs((duration2 / duration1) - 1); 
}
```

Or better because you have less calculations

```
var distance = Math.abs((duration2 / duration1) - 1); 
if (distance > 0.08) {
    return distance;
}
return 1;
```

Note is not clear if you need an absolute percentage or a signed percentage. Changing from the first to the second is possible removing the function Math.abs

Answer (score 0):

```
var d1 = 100; // trusted
var d2 = 108; // other
var diff = d2 - d1;
var percent = (diff / d1) * 100;
console.log(percent, "%");
if(Math.abs(percent) > 8) {
    console.log("Ut oh");
} else {
    console.log("In the sweet spot");
}
```